# Is it possible to add values to table widget programmatically in Google Appmakers

Tags: google-app-maker

I am able to show the data source data in google app maker table widget, but I don not know how to show **static values (array of object) to table widgets** programmatically.
I am new to app maker,I don not know is it possible to add values to table widget programmatically or not.
If any one knows please help me...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Depending on your static values (array of object) you could consider creating a 'Calculated Datasource' and defining your static array in this datasource and then setting our table datasource to the calculated datasource. Otherwise, you may need to look at setting your own createChildren method to append App Maker panels to a more custom table that you will need to create from scratch more or less.

Comment: Thank you Markus. I am pretty new to this technology. Can u provide a small example of createChildren related to the table.

Comment: Any resource where I can learn App maker. I go through the App maker official web site and I also go through the app maker university but still not enough.

Comment: I'd say that resources are a bit slim outside of the AM documentation and AM University. I personally had about 2 years experience with Google Apps Script before they released AM, but even GAS I learned everything myself from heavy research using SO and general web searches. I provided a small sample of what you might need to do to call your own create children method as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To call your own create children method you would want to set up a panel similar to the picture provided and set a datasource for that panel for which items you want to appear in that panel.

[image: Example Pic]

Then go to events for that panel and in the onDataLoad event enter the following code as it pertains to your own data. In my example I used a datasource called employees, and I created a label with the employee name for each item in the datasource.

```
widget.datasource.items.forEach(function(item) {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.className = 'app-Label';
  node.style.margin = '8px';
  node.textContent = item.EmployeeName;
  widget.getElement().appendChild(node);
});
```

That is about the simplest example I have. In the case of a table you would want to create your own base container, a header, and then a container that holds all your table rows. Then in your table body you would set up a similar script that attaches row panels and in the row panels you would create your labels. This would also be possible to declare your own array of objects and loop over each object this way.

Comment: Thanks, Markus for your time and effort. I will try this example